# Can I use IFDEF commands in SQL scripts to enter engine specific commands?

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird

I have a SQL script to create a SQL Server database. I now want to create the same database using Firebird.

Obviously, I need to change the SQL script in parts to make it work with Firebird. Is it possible to use `IFDEF` commands (e.g. `$IFDEF FIREBIRD ... $ELSE ... $ENDIF`) or something similar to stick to one script but to cover the differences between the database engines?

Comment: It will be much easier to have 2 (or several) separate, platform-specific scripts.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Liquibase to manage DBMS independent scripts

Comment: Use Version control like Git. Maintain SQL-standard compliant main branch and also maintain MS-SQL specific and Firebird specific forks of it. I guess Liquibase tries to semi-automatize it....
Additionally, I'm afraid that locks-based MS SQL and versions-based Firebird are so different inside, that using non-bare-SQL features of both might lead to the general database design biased to one engine or another. I am not really sure why DB Schema should be different, not the requests that you hardcode into the application.